# Add up prices for total price with array values PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm making a Shopping Cart, actually it's almost finished now. I only want to calculate the total price. The problem is, the prices per product are calculated (price*quantity) in an foreach loop, so I'm not sure how to add up all the prices.

The PHP Function:

```
    public function getCart(){
    $cartArray = array();
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
        if($_SESSION['cart'] != ""){
            $cart = json_decode($_SESSION['cart'], true);
            for($i=0;$i<count($cart);$i++){
                $lines = $this->getProductData($cart[$i]["product"]);
                $line = new stdClass;
                $line->id = $cart[$i]["product"];
                $line->count = $cart[$i]["count"];
                $line->product = $lines->product;
                $line->total = ($lines->price*$cart[$i]["count"]);
                $cartArray[] = $line;
            }
        }
    }
    return $cartArray;
}
```

How I display it all:

```
<?php
    $cart = new cart();
    $products = $cart->getCart();

    $cartCount = 0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $cart = json_decode($_SESSION['cart'], true);
        $cartCount = count($cart);
    }
    if($cartCount > 0){
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><b>Product</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Quantity</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>Total</b></td>
        <td align="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        foreach($products as $product){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><?php print $product->product; ?></td>

            <td align="center">
                <?php print $product->count; ?>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-minus lessQuantity" 
                data-id="<?php print $product->id; ?>"></i>
                <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa fa-plus addQuantity" 
                data-id="<?php print $product->id; ?>"></i>
            </td>

            <td align="center">$<?php print $product->total; ?></td>

            <td align="right">
                <span style="cursor:pointer;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete item." 
                class="removeFromCart" data-id="<?php print $product->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        }
        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">No products in shopping cart!</div>';
        }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><b>Total: $ Amount</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So this rule calculates the price:

```
$line->total = ($lines->price*$cart[$i]["count"]);
```

But all the results from that line I want to be added up to a total price. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Maybe add a grand total variable and do something like this in the `foreach` loop: `$grand_total += $line->total;`

Comment: Btw, how come you save the session data as json? You can save arrays in sessions (the $_SESSION super global is actually an array itself). No need to encode/decode the cart...

Comment: It's for school purpose, I'm still learning and this was something I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the product totals to a new variable.

When looping out the cart:

```
<?php
    $amount = 0;
    foreach($products as $product){
        $amount += $product->total;
?>
```

After the loop:

```
<td align="right"><b>Total: <?= $amount ?></b></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just adding a new variable where sum the previous prices and add this variable to your `$cartArray`:

```
public function getCart(){
    $cartArray = array();
    $cartArray["products"] = array();
    $totalCart = 0;
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])){
        if($_SESSION['cart'] != ""){
            $cart = json_decode($_SESSION['cart'], true);
            for($i=0;$i<count($cart);$i++){
                $lines = $this->getProductData($cart[$i]["product"]);
                $line = new stdClass;
                $line->id = $cart[$i]["product"];
                $line->count = $cart[$i]["count"];
                $line->product = $lines->product;
                $line->total = ($lines->price*$cart[$i]["count"]);
                $totalCart += $line->total;
                $cartArray["products"][] = $line;
            }
        }
    }
    $cartArray["total"] = $totalCart;
    return $cartArray;
}
```

This will return an array like this:

```
Array(
   "products" => Array(
       [0] = ...
       [1] = ...
   ),
   "total" => 300
);
```